# Non-abundant sums Problem_23

Tags: python, python-3.x

A perfect number is a number for which the sum of its proper divisors is exactly equal to the number. For example, the sum of the proper divisors of 28 would be 1 + 2 + 4 + 7 + 14 = 28, which means that 28 is a perfect number.

A number n is called deficient if the sum of its proper divisors is less than n and it is called abundant if this sum exceeds n.

As 12 is the smallest abundant number, 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6 = 16, the smallest number that can be written as the sum of two abundant numbers is 24. By mathematical analysis, it can be shown that all integers greater than 28123 can be written as the sum of two abundant numbers. However, this upper limit cannot be reduced any further by analysis even though it is known that the greatest number that cannot be expressed as the sum of two abundant numbers is less than this limit.

Find the sum of all the positive integers which cannot be written as the sum of two abundant numbers.

In order to calculate the non-abn. sums ,I am calculating the following:

> step 1: sum of all integers from 1 to 28123(inclusive)
>
> step 2: I am calculating abundant sums i.e 24+30... (since 12 is abn. no. 1st abn.sum is 24) up to or less than 28124
>
> step3: non-abn.sum = tot_sum - abn_sum

But I am getting wrong answer. Little help please!! Thanks in advance.

The correct answer shall be : 4179871

Below you see my o/p:

[image: Click here to see my o/p]

```
abn=[]  #to store abundant nos.
def factors(n):
    s=1 
    if n==1:
        return 1
    if n%2==0:
        step=1
    else:
        step=2

    r=int(n**.5)

    if(r**2==n):
        r-=1
        s+=r+1
        # s-sum 
    f=2
    #print("n= ",n)
    while(f<=r):
        if n%f==0:
            s+=f+n//f
            #print(f,n//f)
        if(s>n):
            abn.append(n)   #if sum is going to be greater than n iam storing them in abn list
            return n
        f+=step    
    else:
        return 0

for i in range(12,28124):  #since 12 is the first abn. no the range starts from 12
    factors(i)
print("List work Done")  #making a list containing abnd. nos

def sum_abn_nos(t):  #making a list containing sum of two abn nos.
    l=[]
    count=0
    print("Len of inp: ",len(t))
    for i in range(len(t)):
        for j in range(i,len(t)):
            if(t[i]+t[j] <=28123):          #since i need only upto 28123
                l.append(t[i]+t[j])
                count+=1
            else:
                break

    print("Len(o/p: t) = ",count)
    return l

def main():
    global abn
    t=sum_abn_nos(abn)
    t.sort()
    print(abn[0:11])
    l=len(abn)
    print("sorting done")
    print("len(abn) ",l)
    print("Len(t)= ",len(t),"t[last]= ",t[len(t)-1])
    i=s1=0
    #print("len(l)= ",len(l))
    while(l>0):  #since only 6903 abn. nos. are in the range 12 to 28124
        s1+=t[i] #i guess the problem is due to this loop only
        i+=1
        l-=1
    #s1= sum(t)  #if i use this line commenting the above while loop iam getting a negative answer
    print("List work 2 Done")
    print("t[0:10]= ",t[0:11]," t[last]= ",t[len(t)-1])
    print("sum1 = ",s1)  #s1 represents abn.sum 
    s2=0
    s2=0
    s2=28123*28124
    s2=s2//2  # sum of n natural nos: formula: (n*(n+1))/2        
    print("Non - abn sum = ",s2-s1)

main()
```

Comment: `if n % 2 == 0: step = 1...` would work fine for odd numbers, but you start with `f = 2` instead of `f = 3` in that case.

Comment: `if(s>n):` should be nested under the preceding `if`. No need to check if the sum hasn't changed.

Comment: I'm guessing that there are some odd abundant numbers and you're skipping them.

Comment: In `sum_abn_nos`, you aren't checking for duplicates properly. There are probably numbers that are the sum of more than one distinct pair of abundants. Make `l` into a `set` instead of a list, and get rid of `count` while you're at it. `len(l)` is all you need.

Comment: Thanks actually I had made that change(f=2) early but didn't save the program it seems, **eventhough now I have rectified it iam not getting the right answer**

Comment: You are skipping abundant numbers. There are 6965, not 6903 numbers in the given range. And I can only strongly advise you to have clearly defined subroutines a main program calls, so you can test the validity of each subroutine individually.

Comment: What did you rectify? If you're dealing with an odd number, start with f=3 instead.

Comment: I rectified f= 3 for odd nos. and also getting 6965 nos. still my answer is wrong.